# How to concatenate data of a column in continuous rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server like this:

```
Table1:

Id    Symbol
1     a
5     c
8     d
3     b
```

I want sort data based on *`Id`* and concatenate *`symbol`* in **continuous** rows:

```
Query Result:

Id    Symbol
1     ab
3     bc
5     cd
8     d
```

What is best query for this result?

Comment: best way is depends on which SQL version are you using? there are many possible ways for these. Left Join / Lag() etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 +:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    symbol + ISNULL(LEAD(symbol) OVER (ORDER BY Id), '') as symbole
FROM
    t
```

or in older versions:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS rn
FROM
    t)
SELECT t1.Id, t1.symbol + ISNULL(t2.symbol, '') As symbole
FROM CTE t1
    LEFT JOIN CTE t2
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Common Table Expression`.

Give a row_number order by id.

**Query**

```
;with cte as
(
  select rn=row_number() over
  (
    order by id
  ),id,symbol
  from table1
)
select t2.id,coalesce(t2.symbol+t1.symbol,t2.symbol) as symbol
from cte t1 
right join cte t2
on t1.rn=t2.rn+1;
```

[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0cad/1)